# Not able to play mpeg 4 video with video codec MPEG-4 Video (Simple Profile) in mat-video and video

Tags: html, video, html5-video, angular7

I am playing video in mat-video and video tag, but none of them playing video which has video codec type as mpeg 4 (simple profile)
however H.264  codec format is playing fine.
is there any way to support mpeg 4 codec in video tag
I tried :

```
<html>
<video>
    <source src="videoUrl"  type='video/mp4; codecs="amp4v.20.8,mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
</html>


<mat-video title="{{videoTitle}}" [autoplay]="true" [preload]="true" [fullscreen]="true" [download]="false">
<source matVideoSource [src]="videoFileName" type='video/mp4;codecs="amp4v.20.8,mp4a.40.2"'>
</mat-video>
```

Tried adding multiple codecs but none of them worked.

Comment: No, only h.264, and Vp9. Some browsers may support HEVC, or AV1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not play video with 'mpeg-4 video' codec . For that you will have to convert video codec to 'h.264' from any converter.
I had also faced similar issue and I managed to convert this video through AWS media convert service.
With AWS media convert SDK , I converted around 500 video by submitting batchJobs via nodejs script using their SDK.

Examples can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/emc-examples-templates.html